# Is it ok to use php __destruct method in this case

Tags: php, oop, destructor

I'm new to php so I need some advices from you. Here is a simple class that I wrote.

```
class Logger
{
    private $handle;

    public function readFile($filename)
    {
        $this->handle = fopen($filename, 'a+');
    }

    public function writeFile($strData)
    {
        fwrite($this->handle, $strData);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        fclose($this->handle);
    }
}
```

It's working well. I'm not sure about the __destruct. Is this a correct place to put fclose in this case or it will be better if I add a close method?

Comment: I'd certainly rename the readFile method to something more meaningful, like openFile, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! Putting the close() in the destructor means that it will always be called when the object is destroyed, even if you forget to call a defined close method, so it's logical to put it there.... though something as basic as close() would be done anyway, so it's not a best use case for a destructor. Using a destructor is more use when explicit processing is required, rather than something that would happen anyway, such as writing additional lines to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opening file when create an instance of Logger, you may not want to close file in destructor.